# Gaussian linear model

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let a vector $X = (X_1,...,X_n)$ has a normal distribution $N(ab,σ^2Σ)$, where $b$ is a known vector size of $n$, $Σ$ is a known positive definite matrix, $a$ and $σ^2$ are unknown parameters. How to reduce the problem to a linear Gaussian model? Gaussian linear model:
$$
X = l + \epsilon
$$
where $l$ is the parameter, $\epsilon$ has a normal distribution $N(0, \sigma I_n)$, where $I_n$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, are you asking how to reduce this to a least squares problem? I believe there is a reduction so that $\hat X = a^T b + \gamma$ for a particular $\hat X$ and iid $\gamma$, where you solve for $a$ using standard techniques. Is that what you're interested in?

Comment: @njwfish I want to reduce my problem to linear Gaussian model, definition of this model is written below in my question